# Visual Studio 2013 - design view doesnt match runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm having a strange issue with visual Studio 2013.  My team and I use Team Foundation for a vb.net windows forms app..when I open forms in designer mode the form controls as scrunched up together, some labels are overwriting others or bleeding in to other controls.. ~

Other team members dont have the same issue... ps.  We use Remote Desktop on to server to launch  Visual Studio so should all be using the same desktop settings.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing someone on your team has a high-DPI display. WinForms does not work well with high-DPI, but things get better with .NET Framework 4.8 - but if you're stuck on VS2013 then *you should update* to VS2019. You said everyone uses RDP, but RDP (by default) respects the client's DPI, and is isn't necessarily fixed on the server.

Comment: "We use Remote Desktop on to server to launch  Visual Studio so should all be using the same desktop settings." - remind me to never work at your company. That's _horrible_.

Comment: @Dai "High-DPI" Can you tell me how I can adjust or set this please?  is it per session or per form setting?

Comment: If you're asking me what High-DPI is or how to handle high-DPI in WinForms then methinks _you have a lot to learn_... You can start by first **UPDATE TO .NET 4.8  AND VISUAL STUDIO 2019 ALREADY**, and then read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @Dai We cant update to VS 2019 due to compatibility issues.  We have to use VS 2013 for the foreseeable.  ps. yes I do have a lot to learn. I'm a VB 6 programmer who has recently moved to vb.net and vs 2013.

Comment: "We cant update to VS 2019 due to compatibility issues" - please tell me what the compatibility issues are - as far as I know there are no significant backwards (nor forwards) compatibility issues between VS2012, VS2013, VS2015, VS2017 and VS2019 - unless you really want to run it on Windows 7 for some reason.

Comment: I recommend you switch to C# and away from VB.NET: seeming as VB.NET is effectively dead at this point (Microsoft no-longer supports it in ASP.NET Core, for example).